# Does Unity support tree data structures?

Tags: unity, c#, tree

I'm really confused. Is it possible to use trees like binary trees or data structures in Unity?

I need to introduce artificial intelligence into my game, and use the A* algorithm.

Comment: Absolutely not. Unity performs occasional checks and if trees are found in your source code, all of your code gets confiscated. On a more serious note: Why do you seem to believe that it's not possible?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 what are you talking about ? did you check DMGregory answer???

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's possible to use trees! Just to name a few, we use...

- [Quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), [Octrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree), [K-D Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), and [BSP Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) to partition 3D scenes for rendering and physics optimizations, among other uses in speeding up work on multidimensional data.
- [Behaviour Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_tree_(artificial_intelligence,_robotics_and_control)) for expressing flexible artificial intelligence logic for NPCs.
- [Game Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_tree) for planning by AI opponents or hint systems.
- [Transformation hierarchies](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Hierarchy.html) for organizing objects in our scenes and setting up compound objects with independently moving parts, like the [skeleton of a skinned mesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation).

As Tyyppi_77 notes in a comment above, it's hard to imagine a useful programming system in which it's *not* possible to use trees. Have you encountered any difficulty implementing a particular tree-based algorithm that you're looking for help with?

Comment: thnx a lot !  actually  I'll make a game  like the 'dots and boxes' one .. but I still collecting informations and ideas before starting.

Comment: hi @DMGregory did you check the Tyyppi_77 comments i am absolutely surprised

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan You did catch Tyyppi_77's sarcasm, yes? Or are you just joking around as well? ;)